# Shifting a JavaScript array one spot to the left without using the .shift( ) method. Algorithm Challenge

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I'm stuck on this algorithm challenge and can't figure out a way to do it. I'm trying to avoid using the .shift() method.

Let's say I have an array of "var x = [1,5,10,7,-2]" and what i'm trying to do is shift it one spot to the left while deleting the first item in the array which is "1". Also I would like to add 0 to the end of the array to replace the spot. The goal is to make the array to be "var x = [5,10,7,-2,0]", I would imagine using a for loop to achieve this. So i'm basically swapping out the first member of the array and swapping in 0 at the end of the array.

I'm not allowed to use reverse or sort method.  The only method i'm allowed to use with this problem is .length. .pop, or .push. I can also use the for loop and if else statements. These are what I am limited to.

Comment: So you can't use the indexer, right?

Comment: What should happen for sparse arrays? e.g. should `[1,2,,4]` become `[2,,4,0]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a for loop

```
for(var i = 1; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i-1] = x[i];
}

x[x.length-1] = 0;
```

Comment: It's not that I have to use them. It's that if it is necessary to use them, then I can. Those are just the methods i'm limited to.

Comment: However, this is the answer I was looking for! Sorry for my poor explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Or even shorter...

```
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i += 1) {
    x[i] = x[i + 1] || 0;
}
```

Comment: Oops. If the value of a member of *x* is falsy but not zero, say *null* or *undefined* (or doesn't exist at all), this will replace it with zero.

Comment: Yeah that's the idea. The last iteration will evaluate x[i + 1] as undefined. This assigns 0 to the last index of the array.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to maintain sparse arrays and only have a loop at your disposal, then the algorithm needs to test for members before copying them:

```
function shiftLeft(arr) {
  for (var i=1, iLen=arr.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    if (arr.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
      arr[i-1] = arr[i];
    } else {
      delete arr[i-1];
    }
  }
  arr[i-1] = 0;
  return arr;
}
```

which can be reduced to:

```
function shiftLeft(arr) {
  for (var i=1, iLen=arr.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    arr.hasOwnProperty(i)? arr[i-1] = arr[i] : delete arr[i-1];
  }
  arr[i-1] = 0;
  return arr;
}
```

Which is less code but not as simple and probably slower.

Comment: Wouldn't `.hasOwnProperty` violate the restrictions stated in the question?

Comment: Maybe, I thought there were only restrictions on array methods. It's the only way I know to preserve sparse arrays. The accepted answer doesn't do that, so maybe the OP doesn't care about it.